# Can i put an array in mysql select?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

Can i put an array in mysql select ?

```
$usersArray = array(34, 23, 17, 17, 56);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$usersArray");
```

Can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I believe this is how you should do that:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(', ', $usersArray) . ")");
```

Comment: it verifies if a value (or field) is in a given set (which can be a select statement). Returns true on first match.

Comment: What can i do if i want search for 2 field like user_id and user_name

Comment: That's a separate question one would be pressed for space to answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$usersArray = array(34, 23, 17, 17, 56);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in (".
    implode(",",$usersArray).
    ")");
```

This is unsafe, as in placing sql parameters as concatenated strings. But you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$usersArray = array(34, 23, 17, 17, 56);
$usersIn = implode(",",$usersArray);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id in($usersIn)");
```

The "in" does a comparison of user_id against any of the entries in the comma separated list within the brackets.